# Why doesn't HTML5 read my css?

Tags: html, css

No matter what i tried or changed it didnt work. My CSS file is in the same folder as my HTML. Here's the code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
     <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
       <title>Photos'r'us</title>
      <div="header">
         <img id="banner" src="https://i.imgur.com/iTt5U3E.jpg" alt:"pic">
          <ul id="navigation">
             <li>Home</li>
             <li>About</li>
             <li>Portfolio</li>
             <li>Contact</li>
              </ul>
        </div>
      </head>
      <body>
      </body>
       </html>
```

and this is the CSS:

```
@charset "UTF-8";

#header {
height: 230px;
background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/iTt5U3E.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
font-family: 'Ariel', sans-serif;
}
#banner {
float: left;
width: 100px;
height: 400px;
margin: 20px;
}
#navigation {
display: inline;
}
```

please help.

Comment: What exactly means _doesn't read_?

Comment: For starters, your HTML is completely invalid. You have your content in the `head` instead of the `body`, invalid elements (`<div="header">`), invalid attributes (`alt:"pic"`) and so on.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen it's not reason to not use valid rules from CSS for `#banner` and `#navigation`. `#header` doesn't exist in HTML, that's true.

Comment: I fixed the HTML, moving the elements into <body>. What i mean is whatever i configure in CSS just doesnt show on the site itself, it displays the pure HTML elements and that alone.

Comment: https://validator.w3.org

Answer (score 1):

Put your all the elements into the `body` tag not in the `head` and correct this line `<div="header">` to `<div id="header">`.

For more help on html read this: [The global structure of an HTML document](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html)

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
#header {
  height: 230px;
  background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/iTt5U3E.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  font-family: 'Ariel', sans-serif;
}

#banner {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 20px;
}

#navigation {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Photos'r'us</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="header">
    <img id="banner" src="https://i.imgur.com/iTt5U3E.jpg" alt="pic">
    <ul id="navigation">
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>About</li>
      <li>Portfolio</li>
      <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong attribute syntax

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

#header {
height: 230px;
background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/iTt5U3E.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
font-family: 'Ariel', sans-serif;
}
#banner {
float: left;
width: 100px;
height: 80px;
margin: 20px;
}
#navigation {
display: inline;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
     <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
       <title>Photos'r'us</title>
      </head>
      <body>
      <div id="header">
         <img id="banner" src="https://i.imgur.com/iTt5U3E.jpg"  alt="pic">
          <ul id="navigation">
             <li>Home</li>
             <li>About</li>
             <li>Portfolio</li>
             <li>Contact</li>
              </ul>
        </div>
      </body>
       </html>
```

1. `id` was missing here `<div id="header">`
2. `alt="pic"` was set wrongly

I changed `width:80px;` to better display, And its working .

Comment: Also, the content shouldn't be in the `<head>` section?

Comment: While you're at it, might as well move the content to the `body`.

Comment: Yes @chade_ : It should be

Comment: @chade_ it isn't in real, look into DOM generated in the code snippet.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! But for some reason it still doesn't read my CSS file! it just doesn't seem to locate it! what the hell? i got two notepads in the same folder one is .HTML one is called style.css